# How to create a virtual midi device in Java

Tags: java, midi

As the title says I'm currently looking for a solution for my java code
so far I stopped here

```
void startMIDI(){
    try {
        Sequence sequence = MidiSystem.getSequence(new File(textField.getText()));
        // Code
    } catch (InvalidMidiDataException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

so now what do I have to do so it allows me to get this sequence of midi signal and send it throughout a portable midi port "textField.getText()" is the destination of my midi file, so I want this midi file to run on that port like I am playing it on a piano and through a midi cable!

One last thing is that I don't want the virtualMIDI SDK, because I didn't understand a word from it, and in fact it didn't help in my project.

Comment: I do not understand your description. Do you want to send the MIDI data to another program? To a real MIDI port?

Comment: I want to create a virtual driver Im just asking if it is possible!

Comment: The only one I've found is VirtualMIDI SDK, but it costs: https://www.tobias-erichsen.de/software/virtualmidi/virtualmidi-sdk.html. Did you find a solution?